# Modifying Excel's Solver

Tags: vba, excel

For excel's solver, I've been able to go in and modify the largest number of variables. However, I can't save the modified solver, and it won't run with a higher number of variables. I've gone through the code, and can't see a reason why it won't allow the higher number of variables, except for the fact that the solver won't save. How can I get the solver to save and run with more variables?

Additionally, how can I force excel to try a bit harder with the solver, since it will frequently claim no solutions, and I'm able to find solutions, that fit with the constraints I'm feeding the solver.

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried so far. Sometimes I understand explanation well when I can co relate with some piece of code.

Comment: What about going to Frontline and getting the Premium Solver? Capable of many more variables etc or is it that it is not free? The second part of your question - have you checked the "options" and tried changing the limits for the solutions?

Comment: Work doesn't permit downloads, so I'm working with what I've got. Otherwise I'd download several more extension to make it work better (knapsack problem... might go the route of finding a pre-built one). I've tried tweaking every setting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify Solver like you think you can.  Maybe you should try something else, like Crystal Ball, from Oracle.

Comment: I've actually gone to using VBA for my needs - mostly working.